# Change App icon dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I need to implement the App icon like default calender or clock application in ios.Which means i need to change the text inside the App icon.Is it possible to change the Appicon dynamically.Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: No. It is not possible.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but this isn't possible. The Calender and Clock apps are Apples own apps so they don't need to stick to the rules they can do whatever the hell they like (Obviously since iOS is Apples' product) as for the rest of us developers we live in a world of rules and restrictions :(